# How can I get the environment variables in templ and golang?

Tags: go

I'm trying to detect whether the environment is in production or development. Additionally, I'd like to pass some public keys such as Segment.

I'm currently using Go and templ

```html
templ Layout(props *LayoutProps) {
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" class="dark h-12 bg-yellow-700">    
            <title>{ props.title }</title>
            {env := os.Getenv("ENVIRONMENT")}
    </html>
}
```

I've tried many things, but I haven't cracked the syntax for it.

Another option is to get the environment from Go, and pass it to the templ. Is that the way to go?

Comment: "Another option is to get the environment from Go, and pass it to the templ. Is that the way to go?" Exactly.

Comment: In general, you should only use `os.Getenv()` in your application bootstrap (eg `main` package) and inject the values into your application from there. Reading from the env all over your codebase is a great way to create a maintenance mess. :)